Hunters of the Dawn
In Arthur C. Clarke's 1979 Fountains of Paradise, the Hunters of the Dawn are mentioned in passing. Were these aliens a bigger presence in another of his stories?
Also Ian Douglas in his 1998 Heritage Series also has an alien Hunters of Dawn with a very similar concept.
Are the Hunters of the Dawn a recycled science fiction concept or trope?

Where in Fountains of Paradise is the reference?

It's a "blink and you miss it" reference, on the last page of the Epilogue.
